# Why should I use ILogger or Serilog?

Tags: asp.net-core, logging

As the question suggests, why should I use ILogger or Serilog or any other 3rd party logger for that matter. I have absolutely nothing against either or any 3rd party loggers. I've traditionally always rolled my own, I don't find it difficult or time consuming, more often than not I've just reused/rehashed something I've written before.

I'm not looking to bash anything. But from what I've read they pretty much do what my logger does and that's just simple messages and time stamps so I can see whats going on. I capture this

```
Date/Time
Message or error message
Module that added the log (name)
Logged in user (if my app has users)
```

I'm just looking to see what the community thinks

Comment: "Why should I use ILogger". Who told you that you should? You should not. It's your choice to use 3rd party library developed for you or invent you own logger, probably even more customizable.

Comment: No one told me to I just hear people raving on about them and wondered what all the fuss was about

Answer (score 1):

For Serilog, I've recently been through a series of article that explains it fairly well: https://ranjeet.dev/All-about-structured-logging-introduction/

The main reason is to leverage structured logging, which consists in adding machine friendly meta data, on top of classical human friendly string based logging. When you end up with a big system in production, this is a gamer changer, because going through Gb of text files would be very unproductive. Then, on top of that, you get a very well thought framework with addins and integration to easily manipulate your logs.